# Is it possible to have tick stepSize for each dataset in Chart.js?

Tags: chart.js

I would like to have a second dataset a little bit smaller then the original one.

this is the first (main bar chart):

```
scales: {
          yAxes: [
            {
              ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true,
                precision: 2,
                stepSize: 0.75,
                // stepValue: 5,
                max: 3 //max value for the chart is 60
              }
            }
          ]
        },
```

and I want to have bigger steps in the second (line chart). So something like this:

```
datasets: [
          {
            label: "Monatswerte",
            data: dataForBar,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)",
            borderColor: "rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)",
            borderWidth: 0.5
          },
          {
            label: "Kummulation",
            data: dataForLine,
            type: "line",
            backgroundColor: "transparent",
            borderColor: "rgba(232, 62, 140, 0.5)",
            borderWidth: 1,
            datalabels: {
              display: false
            },
            ticks: {
              stepSize: 2,
              max: 15
            }
          }
        ]
```

Full Chart here: https://hastebin.com/volocajawu.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I needed to do is giving each dataset an ID `yAxisID: 'axis-months',` and then in option I needed to define a option specified for each ID:

```
scales: {
  yAxes: [
    {
      id: 'axis-months',
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        stepSize: scaleBar * 0.2,
        max: scaleBar
      }
    },
    {
      id: 'axis-accumulation',
      gridLines: {
        display: false
      },
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true
      },
      position: 'right'
    }
  ]
},
```